# How to use Immutabality helper update to modify Redux state object

Tags: redux, immutability

I am trying to use immutabality-helper function update to add a new item to an object.I have an object 'variables' in my Redux store like so.

```
const initialState = {
        variables: {
            a: {},
            b: {}
        }
}
```

The reducer I have tried

```
case ADD_VARIABLE:
   let newVariable = action.payload.newVariable;
   return update(state, {variables: {$merge:newVariable}
   });
```

The resultant 'variables' object  I get when I try to add a new variable 'c' is

```
        variables: {
            a: {},
            b: {},
            key: "c"
        }
```

How do I get a result that looks like

```
        variables: {
            a: {},
            b: {},
            c: {}
        }
```

Comment: Not very familiar with immutability-helper but based on docs see if this helps `return update(state, {variables: {$merge: {newVariable}}` OR `return update(state, {variables: {$merge: {c: newVariable}}`

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out myself.

```
case ADD_VARIABLE:
   let newVariable = action.payload.newVariable;
   return update(state, {variables: {$merge: {[newVariable]:{}}}
```

});